# ¿Como refrescar una página usando React y Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

el problema en el que me encuentro es que haciendo el frontend de una pagina web de pujas de productos, necesito refrescar la página en la que se realizan las pujas.

Esa página esta conformada por el detalle del producto especificando nombre, tiempo restante para que expire el producto, el precio actual de la puja, etc. Debajo se encuentra un formulario para que el usuario puje sobre ese producto introduciendo una cantidad. En el momento que el usuario introduce la cantidad por la que quiere pujar sobre el producto y haga click en pujar, la página en la que está se tiene que actualizar y por ejemplo el precio actual de la puja se tiene que modificar sin que el usuario tenga que salir de esa página y volver a entrar.

Yo lo como intenté hacer es que cuando el usuario pulse pujar, la pagina haga un push de la url en la que está para ver si así se actualiza, pero no. Adjunto el código para más ayuda

Pagina que que se tiene que refrescar que tiene detalles del producto más el formulario para pujar [ProductDetails.js]

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FormattedMessage, FormattedNumber, FormattedDate, FormattedTime } from 'react-intl';

import users from '../../users';
import * as selectors from '../selectors';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import {BidUpForm} from '../../adverts';
import {BackLink} from '../../common';

class ProductDetails extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        const id = Number(this.props.match.params.id);

        if (!Number.isNaN(id)) {
            this.props.findProductById(id);
        }

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.clearProduct();
    }

    render() {

        const product = this.props.product;

        if (!product) {
            return null;
        }

        return (

            <div>

                <BackLink/>

                <div className="card text-center">
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{product.name}</h5>
                        <h6 className="card-subtitle text-muted">
                            <FormattedMessage id='project.global.fields.department' />:&nbsp;
                                {selectors.getCategoryName(this.props.categories, product.categoryId)}
                        </h6>
                        <p className="card-text">{product.description}</p>
                        <p className="card-text">
                            <FormattedMessage id='project.global.fields.userName' />
                            : {product.userName}
                        </p>
                        <p className="card-text font-weight-bold">
                            <FormattedMessage id='project.global.fields.date' />
                            : <FormattedDate value={new Date(product.date)} /> - <FormattedTime value={new Date(product.date)}/>
                        </p>
                        <p className="card-text">
                            <FormattedMessage id='project.global.fields.duration' />
                            : {product.duration == -1 ? <FormattedMessage id='project.global.fields.finalized'/> :
                            product.duration} 
                        </p>
                        <p className="card-text font-weight-bold">
                            <FormattedMessage id='project.global.fields.price' />
                            : <FormattedNumber value={product.price} />€
                        </p>
                        <p className="card-text font-weight-bold">
                            <FormattedMessage id='project.global.fields.actualPrice' />
                            : <FormattedNumber value={product.actualPrice} />€
                        </p>
                        <p className="card-text">{product.shipmentInfo}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {this.props.loggedIn && product.duration >= 0 &&
                    <div>
                        <br/>
                        <BidUpForm productId={product.id} 
                            history={this.props.history}/>
                    </div>
                }


            </div>

        );

    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    loggedIn: users.selectors.isLoggedIn(state),
    product: selectors.getProduct(state),
    categories: selectors.getCategories(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    findProductById: actions.findProductById,
    clearProduct: actions.clearProduct
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProductDetails);
```

Formulario de la puja [BidUpForm.js]:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import {Errors} from '../../common';
import * as actions from '../actions';

const initialState = {
    amount : 0,
    backendErrors: null
};

class BidUpForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = initialState;

    }

    handleAmountChange(event) {
        this.setState({amount: Number(event.target.value)});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if (this.form.checkValidity()) {
            this.bidUp();
        } else {
            this.setBackendErrors(null);
            this.form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }

    }

    bidUp() {

        this.props.dispatch(actions.bidUp(this.props.productId, 
            this.state.amount, 
            () => this.props.history.push(`/catalog/product-details/${this.props.productId}`),
            errors => this.setBackendErrors(errors)));

    }

    setBackendErrors(backendErrors) {
        this.setState({backendErrors});
    }

    handleErrorsClose() {
        this.setState({backendErrors: null});
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Errors errors={this.state.backendErrors} 
                    onClose={() => this.handleErrorsClose()}/>
                <div className="card bg-light border-dark">
                    <h5 className="card-header">
                        <FormattedMessage id="project.adverts.BidUpForm.title"/>
                    </h5>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <form ref={node => this.form = node}
                            className="needs-validation" noValidate 
                            onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
                            <div className="form-group row">
                                <label htmlFor="amount" className="col-md-3 col-form-label">
                                    <FormattedMessage id="project.global.fields.amount"/>
                                </label>
                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="number" id="amount" className="form-control"
                                        value={this.state.amount}
                                        onChange={(e) => this.handleAmountChange(e)}
                                        autoFocus
                                        min="1"/>
                                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                        <FormattedMessage id='project.global.validator.required'/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group row">
                                <div className="offset-md-3 col-md-2">
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                                        <FormattedMessage id="project.adverts.BidUpForm.bidUp"/>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

    }

}

BidUpForm = connect()(BidUpForm);

BidUpForm.propTypes = {
    productId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default BidUpForm;
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: No podría proporcionarte una respuesta en el momento, pero sé que te ahorrarías mucho tiempo si pudieses implementar un servicio basado en websockets o con socket.io. De esta forma sería mucho más fácil hacer el pull y el push de los datos